# How can I use wmctrl to check if a certain WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) exists?

Tags: window-manager, i3, window, wmctrl

I'm using I3 and I use WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) to identify my windows.

I'm looking for something similar to this, but with WM_ICON_NAME(STRING). It is possible to achieve this? Thank you.

```
if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "name of my window" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then 
    echo "the window exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There are not many tools that use `WM_ICON_NAME` as it is often assumed to be set to the same as `WM_NAME`. You can list all the window ids and run `xprop` on each of them to get a line such as

```
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "myname"
```

and then use `awk` (or similar) to extract the quoted part of this and compare it to the wanted string. Here's a bash function `findicon` taking one parameter to do this:

```bash
findicon(){ 
    local myname=${1?}
    wmctrl -l |
    while read id rest
    do xprop -id "$id" WM_ICON_NAME
    done |
    awk -F'"' -v myname="$myname" '
        {if($2==myname)found=1} 
        END {exit !found}'
}

if findicon 'my icon name'
then echo 'found'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xdotool` to search existing windows by their class names and titles.

```bsh
if xdotool search --name "name of my window" > /dev/null; then
    echo "Window found"
else
    echo "Window not found"
fi
```

In above code example `xdotool` command will return exit status `0` and list of found window id's if there are some windows which title contains `"name of my window"`.